# SQL Selecting statement, sum function in where

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum, where-clause

I have a table with  a lot of bills. And I need to select the items from the bills where the bill excedes a price.

I tried this :

```
SELECT   d.BillNumber
       , SUM(d1.Amount* d1.Price) 
       , d2.Name AS FinalPrice
FROM GEMsc106Antet d LEFT OUTER JOIN GEMsc106Pozitii d1 
ON d1.Luna = d.Luna AND d1.NumarI = d.NumarI 
JOIN GEcProduse d2 ON d2.Cod = d1.CodMaterial 
WHERE YEAR(d.Data) = 2013 
GROUP BY   d.BillNumber , d2.Name 
HAVING SUM(d1.Amount* d1.Price) >= 10000
```

But this statement seems not to do the trick, as first it selects me only the bill from2013 which is OK, but then I should get all the bills that are greater then 10.000, and I can't use the sum in the where clause and only after that I should GROUP them.

What can I do?

Comment: The query seems fine...You have 3 joins...So if at least one join is not verified the query will skip a lot of results...Try to make tests by removing some joins to make sure when things go wrong

Comment: Is the BillNumber unique? If so you won't need a group by and can simply check amount * price in the where clause

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you don't want to cram *all the logic* into one `select`. Try `with` construction:

```
with data as ( 
       -- Your preliminary data: cheques (?) with bill sum and the actual price
   select d.BillNumber as BillNumber, 
          sum(d1.Amount * d1.Price) as Bill,
          d2.Name as Price
     from GEMsc106Antet d 
            left join
              GEMsc106Pozitii d1 on d1.Luna = d.Luna and d1.NumarI = d.NumarI
            join
              GEcProduse d2 on d2.Cod = d1.CodMaterial 
    where Year(d.Data) = 2013
 group by d.BillNumber, 
          d2.Name)

-- Final query: just use appropriate where condition
select *
  from data
 where Bill > Price
```

Answer (score 0):

This will only work if the BillNumber and d2.Name is unique:

```
SELECT   d.BillNumber
       , d1.Amount* d1.Price 
       , d2.Name AS FinalPrice
FROM GEMsc106Antet d 
LEFT OUTER JOIN GEMsc106Pozitii d1 
   ON d1.Luna = d.Luna AND d1.NumarI = d.NumarI 
JOIN GEcProduse d2 
   ON d2.Cod = d1.CodMaterial 
WHERE YEAR(d.Data) = 2013 AND (d1.Amount* d1.Price) >= 10000
```

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve the problem the query looks like this

```
Select x.Name
from GECProduse x
join GEMSc106Pozitii p on x.Cod= p.CodMaterial
join (Select d.Month, d.NumarI from GeMsc106Antet d 
    join GEMsc106Pozitii d1 on d.Month= d1.Month and d.NumarI=d1.NumarI
    WHERE YEAR(d.Data) = 2013
    GROUP by d.Numar,d.Month, d.NumarI HAVING sum(d1.Quantity*d1.SellingPrice) >= 10000) p1 on p1.Month=p.Month and p1.NumarI=p.NumarI
GROUP BY x.Name
```